# Integration of X and Y in a XYZV csv file

Tags: pandas, csv, math

I am working on a project which essentially has X,Y,Z,Voltage dimensions within a csv file. I am hoping to take this XYZV grid and reduce it to a XYV grid to make a 2D plot. This would require that I take every X,Y pair that is the same and average the Voltage column under different Z values.

i.e

```
X    Y.   Z.  V
1.   0.   1.  10
1.   0.   1.5. 5
1.   0.   0.   1 
1.   1.   1.   1
```

Becomes:

```
X.   Y.   V.  
1.   0.   5.333
1.   1.   1
```

How would I do this in python reading in a csv file either through pandas or csv?

Comment: How you tried looping over the data?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try `groupby_mean`:

```
>>> df.groupby(['X', 'Y'], as_index=False)['V'].mean()
     X    Y         V
0  1.0  0.0  5.333333
1  1.0  1.0  1.000000
```

To read a csv file, use [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):